# Cannot update a component (`ConnectFunction`) while rendering a different component (`TodoDelete`)

Tags: reactjs

[Source code of the file generating the warning message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvsZn.png)

I am trying to build a Todo App using ReactJs and I get the following warning when I delete a todo item

```
Warning: Cannot update a component (`ConnectFunction`) while rendering a different component (`TodoDelete`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `TodoDelete`, follow the stack trace as described in https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/18178#issuecomment-595846312
in TodoDelete (created by ConnectFunction)
in ConnectFunction (created by Context.Consumer)
in Route (at App.js:18)
in Switch (at App.js:14)
in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
in BrowserRouter (at App.js:12)
in App (at src/index.js:22)
in StrictMode (at src/index.js:21)
in Provider (at src/index.js:20)
```

I am not able to understand the reason for this warning. I tried replacing the function with class and still getting the same warning. Can somebody help me?

Comment: I'm curious about this as well. The best solution that I came up with was to move the method (in your case ToDoDelete to the onClick event), but I really don't like that solution because it moves method away from the component.

Comment: I did the following, but I cannot imagine it's a best practice:
   setTimeout(myFunction, 100)

In your case, why don't you just move the functionality to an onClick event rather than creating a separate component?

Comment: I came across the same problem in my functional component,  any official solution or instruments?